# in React JSON Return : Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am getting a syntax error in my React return

Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ","

If I remove

```
{data.nodes && data.nodes.map((node) => (
              {node.title}
              ))}
```

I get a different error BUT I do see all my JSON data in my terminal, so I know it is getting pulled. I am having trouble looping/mapping through it within my return

the error if I remove map...
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

So my logic is to render the data as JSX and then pass it along from GetSlides to Page. You will see the {page} getting passed as well, but that works fine

```
async function GetSlides() {

const data = await getHomeSlides()
console.log(data)

 if (!data) return null;    
    
  return (
    
      <div>
        <h1>Slides</h1>

         {data.nodes && data.nodes.map((node) => (
          {node.title}
          ))}
      
     </div>
  )
    
}

export default function Page( {page} ) {


  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Head>
          <title>{ page.seo.title }</title>
          <meta name="description" content={page.seo.metaDesc} />
        </Head>
       <Header />
        <ContainerFull>
          <h1>{ page.title }</h1>
            <GetSlides />
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: page.content }} />

          
        </ContainerFull>
      </Layout>
    </>
  )
}
```

This is the query

```
const API_URL = process.env.WORDPRESS_API_URL

async function fetchAPI(query, { variables } = {}) {
  const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

  if (process.env.WORDPRESS_AUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN) {
    headers[
      'Authorization'
    ] = `Bearer ${process.env.WORDPRESS_AUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN}`
  }

  const res = await fetch(API_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query,
      variables,
    }),
  })

  const json = await res.json()
  if (json.errors) {
    console.error(json.errors)
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch API')
  }
  return json.data
}

export async function getHomeSlides() {
  const data = await fetchAPI(`
         {
          artwork {
            nodes {
              artwork {
                available
                description
                medium
                price
                size
                arttypedisplay
                homePageSlideshow
              }
              title
              uri
              slug
              seo {
                metaDesc
                title
              }
            }
          }
        }

  `)
  return data?.artwork
}
```

Comment: `{node.title}` isn't valid JSX. What are you trying to render?

Comment: For now, im am trying to loop through the data and display the titles, once that is displayed properly and I can see results I will format it more

Comment: If `node.title` is a string then just remove the brackets (`{}`) and it should be renderable.

Comment: Ok, Now i get the other error
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in GetSlides (at pages/index.js:26)

Comment: that is coming from using <GetSlides /> inside Page function

Comment: Shoot, I didn't see that you tried to make your `GetSlides` component `async`. React doesn't work like that, the render function is 100% synchronous and should be free of side-effects. Do the data fetching in an `useEffect` hook and store result in local component state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227435/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-justin-blayney).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to Drew Reese for the great insight..

the final code invloved putting both queries into  getStaticProps

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Link from 'next/link'
import ContainerFull from '../components/container-full'
import MoreStories from '../components/more-stories'
import HeroPost from '../components/hero-post'
import Intro from '../components/intro'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import { getHomePage, getHomeSlides } from '../lib/api'
import { CMS_NAME } from '../lib/constants'
import Header from '../components/header'


export default function Page( {page, artwork} ) {

    

  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Head>
          <title>{ page.seo.title }</title>
          <meta name="description" content={page.seo.metaDesc} />
        </Head>
       <Header />
        <ContainerFull>
          <h1>{ page.title }</h1>
            
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: page.content }} />

        {artwork.nodes && artwork.nodes.map((arts) => (
          <span>{arts.title}</span>
          ))}
      
          
        </ContainerFull>
      </Layout>
    </>
  )
}



export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    
    
  const data = await getHomePage()
  console.log(data)
  
   const art = await getHomeSlides()
  console.log(art)
  
  return {
    props: {
      page: data,
      artwork: art,
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You tried to make your `GetSlides` component `async`. React doesn't work like that, the render function is 100% synchronous and should be free of side-effects. Do the data fetching in an `useEffect` hook and store result in local component state. An asynchronous function is declared *inside* the effect callback since react hooks are *also* synchronous.

```
function GetSlides() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({
    nodes: [],
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchHomeSlides = async () => { // <-- create async function
      const data = await getHomeSlides()
      console.log(data);
      setData(data);
    };

    fetchHomeSlides(); // <-- invoke on component mount
  }, []); // <-- empty dependency array to run once on mount

  if (!data.nodes.length) return null; // <-- return null if nodes array empty
    
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Slides</h1>

      {data.nodes.map((node, index) => (
        <React.Fragment key={index}> // <-- use react key
          {node.title} // <-- render title
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
    
}
```

Comment: thank you for that.. we both wrote similar ;D code at once.. and both your code and what I wrote get a new error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data  and my terminal no longer displays the data.. FYI, I am using next,js in case that changes anything